# Prove or disprove the following statements

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y:\Bbb R$$\to\Bbb R$ be a solution of the ODE
>   $$\ \dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-y=e^{-x} ,x \in\Bbb R\\ y(0)= y'(0)=0 $$
>
> Then which of the following are true?
>
> 1) $y$ attains its minimum on $\Bbb R$
>
> 2) $y$ is bounded on $\Bbb R$
>
> 3) $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}  e^{-x}y(x)=$${1}\over{4} $
>
> 4) $ \lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}  e^{-x}y(x)=$${1}\over{4} $

I've got the solution as

$y=$ ${e^{x}}\over{4}$ $-$ ${e^{-x}}\over{4}$ $-$ ${xe^{-x}}\over{2}$

So  option 3 is right.

But how to evaluate the 4th option, in which $e^{-x}y(x)$ $=$${1}\over{4}$ $-$ ${e^{-2x}}\over{4}$ $-$ ${xe^{-2x}}\over{2}$.
 Can we say that $y$ is unbounded because of the presence of $e^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$ ?

Comment: your solution already suggests that $y(x)$ is not bounded, right?

Comment: The other half of it:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463445/minimum-value-of-the-solution-of-the-ode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Put $x \to \infty$ in your solution and you will see that option 3 is true. Next find $y'(x)$ and $y{''}(x)$ and put $y'(x) = 0$ then you will get $x=0$ and for $x=0$, $y{''}$ is greater than $0$. So $y(x)$ attains its minimum at $0$ on $\mathbb R$. So option 1 and 3 are correct.